# .NET UDP Client use over internet not working

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, hotspot

I have a rather complex client server app that has three separate UDP connections.

One connection (port 50001) is for control of a device.
This connection listens for connections from a remote device and when a connection is made sends data and receives data.  This works fine over a LAN as well as over the internet.  Of course, port forwarding is enabled on the server network.  This works fine using a mobile phone hot spot as well.

Another connection is for UDP sound being sent from the client to the server (port 50002).  In this case, the client just sends UDP packets to the server using the routers internet IP Address which then by port forwarding goes to the server.  This works fine over the LAN, and the Internet using a mobile phone hot spot.

Now there is a third connection (port 50003) where the issue comes in.This connection is the client receiving sound from the server.  This works if I am on the lan and connect direct to the server or if I specify the Internet address of my router.  But it does not work with a hot spot.

So the question is, is this an issue with the Mobile provider that is just not letting the UDP packets in over port 50003?  Or, am I not connecting correctly to the hotspot?

So this is how the code works:  When the connection is made from the client to the server for control of the device, I get the remote IPEndpoint address and save it.  Next I just start sending the UPD packets from the server to the client using this address.  Again this works over the LAN direct to the client, but it does not work if I use a hot spot.

Here is the code:
Note:address contains the address of the remote client from the first connection:

```
private void Connect(string address, int port) //at this point the control connection is running and the address comes from there
{
    IPAddress destination = IPAddress.Parse(address)
    socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp); 
    endPoint = new IPEndPoint(destination, port);
}

private void SendBytes(Byte[] bytes)
{
    socket.SendTo(bytes, 0 , bytes.,Length, SocketFlags.None, endPoint)
}
```

So this exact same code works in the direction from client to server but in that case I am sending the UDP packets to the router internet address which has port forwarding enabled.  However, it does not work in the direction from server to client. The question is why not?

Is it because a port forward is not available on the hot spot? 
Why is one not needed for the control (Connection one??).

I should mention that the control connection is different than both of these:  It is an async UDP server.

Thanks

Comment: No one at all has a comment?

Comment: So, if I see it correctly, incoming to the server works (due to port forwarding) while incoming to client on hotspot doesn´t. Without exploring the trouble with the hotspot further (it´s probably natted and won´t accept incoming) I´d see if I could establish the third connection from the client too (in order to let the server messages through to the client).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that the problem is on the missing port forwarding of the hot spot is correct.

Often the IP addresses provided by the hot spot are from a private range (e.g. 192.168.x.y) and are translated with NA(P)T to the public IP address of the hot spot.

When you send an UDP message from the client to the server, the router in the hot spot keeps the information of the source and targets IP addresses and ports. When an answer is received using the same IPs and ports, this message is forwarded to the client.

But when you use a different port number, the router doesn't know to who this message should be sent.

If possible, I would suggest that the third connection is also initiated by the client or that the data is sent over one of the other two existing connections.

Comment: Ok so either I have a listener on the server at the port 50003, and start the connection from the client to that listener. Then the clients router would know the route. The alternative is to use the same port as the sound from the client to the server but in the opposite direction. That would work?  The sound is using real time protocol. Is that supported is full duplex?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but the alternative you've described should work as long as the whole path from client to server has enough bandwith up- and downstream.

Comment: Hi, Gave it a shot just changing the port however, it does not work over the mobile hot spot.  I believe it's due to how the connection is made.  So I will add a listener to the sound port which should take care of the issues.  Thanks